# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder Error?

Tags: java

I am encountering the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder however i have imported the classes so am not sure why it is popping up. My build.gradle and code is below:

```
private String getAccessToken() {
    try {
        Log.e("tree","get access entered");
        javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> payload =
                javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.text("grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=https://facebook.com/__");
        javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target("https://v2.api.xapo.com/oauth2/token")
                .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .header("Authorization","Basic ___")
                .post(payload);
Log.e("tree","response completed");
            String body = response.readEntity(String.class);
            Log.e("tree","body "+body);
        } catch(Exception e) {
Log.e("tree","token exception "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: You get that message if the JAR is not in the CLASSPATH at runtime.  This is Java 101.

Comment: If you look at my gradle it appears to be. An example of a fix would help more

Comment: Appears to be is the problem. Check your assumptions.  You understand that import has nothing to do with it, right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are missing the `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client` dependency.

Comment: After that it gives `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`

Comment: the jakarta error is due to a namechange of the package from the old javax to jakarta. see that you have the versions aligning of all jersey dependencies

Comment: @Xtroce Jakarta EE (and its packages) wasn't exist when the question was asked

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `pom.xml`, add the Maven dependency below in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```